# How to do cumulative plots and which statistical test is better?

Tags: r, data-visualization, cumulative-sum, accumulate, statistical-test

I need to do some cumulative plots in R, but I really don't know what to use. I have data like the one below. 
    I want to do some graphs, like shown in the images (below the links). The first showing me that for example 80% of the stops happen when Q is X value. The second one starting from the exceeded value (1mg/l), show the accumulation of stops over time. And the third showing the accumulation of stops over time.

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    | Date      | Stops  |  Q (m3/s)  |  Concentration (mg/L) |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    | 1/01/2009 |  no    |  100       |      0,5              |
    | 2/01/2009 |  no    |  98        |      ---              |
    | 3/01/2009 |  no    |  80        |      ---              |
    | 4/01/2009 |  yes   |  65        |      1,2              |
    | 5/01/2009 |  yes   |  60        |      ---              |
    | 6/01/2009 |  yes   |  67        |      ---              |
    | 7/01/2009 |  no    |  75        |      0,6              |
    | 8/01/2009 |  no    |  70        |      ---              |
    | 9/01/2009 |  no    |  72        |      ---              |
    | 10/01/2009|  yes   |  60        |      1,0              |
    | 11/01/2009|  yes   |  63        |      ---              |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
```

[%stops and discharge][1] [cumulative stops with concentration][2] [cumulative stops over time][3]

The data i'm using is bigger off course, is of 10 years.

After doing the plots I would also like to find the proportion of time where a stop happened with low discharge, or with exceeded concentrations. For example, in the 10 year period, 10 months represent stops.

I'm also looking at the relation of the stops with the other variables, but I'm not sure which test is best for that. I'm planning to use Pearson for the relation of discharge with concentration, although I'm not sure if the discontinuous data of concentration is a problem.  For the relation of Stops with concentration and discharge, I'm planning Spearman rank, but again, I'm not sure if its alright with categorical variables(stops) and the discontinuous data (concentration).  What do you think is the best option for relating this variables?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYdkD.png  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0qNW.png  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nSrF.png

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: You just need to create the data you want to graph. The `cumsum` function will be useful. For example, `your_data$cum_stops = cumsum(your_data$Stops == 'yes')` will give the cumulative count of stops in a new column.

Comment: I think the question should be more suitable for https://stats.stackexchange.com/